# Move Files from a SharePoint Library into a Folder

Tags: document-library, powershell, site, folder, field-definition

I have a problem. I want to move files from a SharePoint library into a folder using PowerShell. To be more specific I need to move all the files in the library for whose a SharePoint field value equals a set value  (Field "Vertrauensstufe"=="vertraulich") to a folder called "geheim".

How can I do that?

Comment: is it sharepoint library folder or your windows folder?

Comment: SharePoint Folder

Comment: do you have a server version or foundation? is it 2010?

Comment: i have a Server Version (Enterprise) and it's 2010

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem statet in your question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I found these script, but it don't need the folder query... but there are some things in (e.g. the Caml-Query and the move function) that i need, but i dont know how i can customize These script for my idea.

[Donwloadlink](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7450902/Powershell-script.txt.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is not required to programm this script in PowerShell you can easily do this in C# and only load DLL into SharePoint: see it [here](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/29/how-to-load-net-assemblies-in-a-powershell-session/).

If you are realy required to do this in PowerShell you can always load DLL of FrameWork into your powerShell consol and do API calls to do what you need.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586989/copy-selected-file-in-sharepoint-to-local-drive/14604844#14604844) the answer I left for similar question. 
And another one: [Using PowerShell how do I change the column ordering for a SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60381/using-powershell-how-do-i-change-the-column-ordering-for-a-sharepoint-list/60393#60393)

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content and Structure to move files to a different place within a site collection. Please see a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k_oNSvxGaI) of usage. But **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** site collection feature should be activated. You will need to select files manually and apply move action.

Comment: An document with the library field value "geheim" in field "Vertrauensstufe" should be automatically move in the folder "vertraulich" in the same library. An command in sharePoint should run the powershell move Skript.

I need realy an powershell script for that Action, but i'm absolutly an beginner in Powershell Scripting. Can someone help me with what?